# Need help to create a join Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

Table 1

```
ID  Status
1   D
2   F
3   D
```

Table 2

```
SID ID  Approve
1   1   N
2   1   Y
3   1   Y
4   2   Y
```

I need a query to joins 2 tables on ID and finds records that don not have N in their Approve column.  Does anyone have any clue how to implement this?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 
ON t2.id = t1.id 
WHERE t2.Approve != 'N'
```

Comment: The Query result is repeating the records in Table 1 as many child rows it have.   The problem is I need only 1 output for a record.  If I add Group by it groups in {Records with Y and Records with N} So it gives one record but shows one with N too.  Any Idea?

Comment: How do you know which child you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id,t1.status,t2.approve FROM Table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 
ON t2.id = t1.id 
WHERE t2.Approve != 'N'
```

you can't have the t2.sid in the select clause though as it will void the DISTINCT criteria.